# Log what templates were used in a django middleware

Tags: django

In Django, is there a reasonably simple way to log what templates were used using a middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) puts an overlay on your webpages when you are in debug mode that shows you what templates were used in a request

I'm sure the source code would show you how to go about this if you wanted it for production